# django: list transfer to template and to JS

Tags: jquery, python, html, django

In Views.py i create a list variable -

```
mortgages_counter.append(MonthlyPaymentAmount)
```

it is transferred to .html template as:

```
<input id ='mortgages_counter' name='mortgages_counter' type='hidden' value='{{mortgages_counter}}'>
```

in JQuery (separate file i have to check if each element of this list is used). value is transferred to .js file as:

```
var mortgages_counter = $('#mortgages_counter').val();
```

but according to console it was transferred as a string to Jquery - like ['1234','125'] and its length is 1 because of some reason,
also check like access to index [0] gives - ' and [1] - 1 etc. 
how to operate with this list as with LIST and NOT a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though @JulienGregoire already answered, I'm mentioning another approach. You can run a loop through the `mortgages_counter` and add each item to an `input` tag. Then in Jquery use [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to go through each object and check.

In your template do something like this.

```
{% for mortgages in mortgages_counter %}
    <input id='mortgages_counter' name='mortgages_counter' type='hidden' value='{{ mortgages }}'>
{% endfor %}
```

And in your Jquery use [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) like this.

```
$("#mortgages_counter").each(function () {
    var mortgage = $(this).val();
    /* do rest of the things and/or comparisons */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the value as a string, which you can do by using `join` filter. Use a separator you know won't be used in the values of the list. Like this for example:

```
<input id ='mortgages_counter' name='mortgages_counter' type='hidden' value='{{mortgages_counter||join:"|" }}'>
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#join

Then you split in javascript using the same separator. It converts the string to an array:

```
var mortgages_counter = $('#mortgages_counter').val().split('|');
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp